# How can I use the automator to create text-to-speech service that talks faster than the current service?

Tags: applescript, automator, services, text-to-speech

The text-to-speech service has a speaking rate option that goes from slow to fast. But the fast option is not fast enough (its 300 words per minute).

I just tried to create a service. I simply dragged the "Speak text" action, saved it and tested it. It seems that my new service still relies on the speed option specified in the preferences.

Is there a way for me to tell it something like "render speech at 400wpm"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

1. Remove the "**Speak text**" action.
2. Add the "**Run AppleScript**" action.
3. Clear all the default text in the action.
4. Copy/paste this script in the action:

> ```
> on run {input, parameters}
>   repeat with thisText in input
>       say thisText speaking rate 400
>   end repeat
> end run
> ```

If you want a specific voice, append `using "SomeVoiceName"` after the `say` command.

Example : `say thisText speaking rate 400 using "Bruce" -- Bruce is a name of the voice`

Comment: This is fantastic. Just one last thing, is there a way to stop the speech? For example, If I select a big chunk of text and decide I don't want to hear it anymore, is there a shortcut to stop the voice? At the moment I know I can click the cogwheel at the top menu bar and delete it from there but is there a shortcut. 
Thanks a lot